# Is it possible to save a jtable in a single column of a mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jtable

I'm working on a project that would act as a record management system. I made a jtable in my project where users can input their work experiences. The table has 3 columns titled "name of company","position",and "no. Of years working experience". Now I want to save their whole work experiences in the database, but I don't know if it's possible to insert a table into a database table.  Can you give some ideas and tutorials or maybe some alternatives?  Thank you. I'm just new to java.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can get your data from the JTable in String variables and then insert them into

```
for(int i=0;i<=jTable.getRowCount;i++){

                String item=jTable.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
                String quant=jTable.getValueAt(i,2 ).toString();
                int unit=jTable.getValueAt(i, 3);
                statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tableName VALUES('"+name_of_company+"','"+position+"','"+experience+"')");
```